# find column name of a specific element in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have a data frame in python with following structure and data

```
'Column1' 'Column2'
 value1   value2
 value3   value4
```

How can find the column name of value4?

I could use data.iloc[0,0] or data.iloc[0:1;0:1] to get 'value1' but how do I find it's label 'Column1' without printing the entire column values or doing a manual check to match using a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can search the value anywhere in the dataframe and drop columns where it is not present:

```
df[df == 'value4'].dropna(axis=1, how='all').columns.tolist()
```

This will return `['Column2']`.

Comment: Thank you as well.

Comment: @Marco: You should *accept* one of the answer (the one that helped most) to notify other readers that you no longer need help about this question. BTW *accept* is the check mark near the answer...

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
c = df.columns[(df == 'value4').any()].tolist()
print (c)
['Column2']
```

If need first match value use `iter` with `next` - if not exist is returned default value:

```
c = next(iter(df.columns[(df == 'value4').any()].tolist()), 'no match')
print (c)
Column2
```

**Details**:

First test all values:

```
print ((df == 'value4'))
   Column1  Column2
0    False    False
1    False     True
```

And then add [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) for test at least one `True` per columns:

```
print ((df == 'value4').any())
Column1    False
Column2     True
dtype: bool
```

Last filter columns names:

```
print (df.columns[(df == 'value4').any()])
Index(['Column2'], dtype='object')
```